# The remote procedure call failed during applying Remote Access Setup Wizard Settings

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dmz, pki, direct-access

I have a DirectAccess server with Windows Server 2012 R2 in the DMZ and other services such as Active Directory (located on a subdomain) and the PKI infrastructure in the internal area.

And I get this error when I try to apply the setting "**Use computer certificates**" in the Remote Access Setup to enable Windows 7 client computers to connect via DirectAccess.

And I get this error when applying the final changes:

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AlOAAiRBk3lngaIfFMh-TPu5uRFzWw

In the events viewer, I only get this:

https://1drv.ms/i/s!AlOAAiRBk3lngaIgv5u8kAQ7ZpSnPg

Does anyone have any idea why this error might be happening?